# Put the system in row echelon form and represent solution as a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the equations
\begin{align}
x_2 + 2x_3 − x_4 + 2x_5 &= 11\\
x_1 + x_2 − x_5 &= 5\\
2x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 + x_4 &= 15\\
\end{align}
Through row operations I got the equations

\begin{align}
2x_1+x_2+2x3+x_4&=15\\
x_2-2x_3-x4-2x_5&=-5\\
x_3+x_5&= 4
\end{align}
It seems that I will have $3$ free variables but I am not sure how to go about solving the equation in echelon form.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $x_4=s$ and $x_5=t$.

Express $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in terms of $s$ and $t$.